# How to upload files in REST API Application on Elixir Phoenix?

Tags: file-upload, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to send file with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and i catch an error:

```
** (Plug.Parsers.ParseError) malformed request, a MatchError exception was raised with message "no match of right hand side value: false"
(cowboy) /home/erlan/Documents/Work/Erlang/Elixir/api_pager/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_req.erl:735: :cowboy_req.init_multipart/1
(cowboy) /home/erlan/Documents/Work/Erlang/Elixir/api_pager/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_req.erl:673: :cowboy_req.part/2
(plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/conn.ex:76: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn.parse_req_multipart/3
(plug) lib/plug/parsers/multipart.ex:17: Plug.Parsers.MULTIPART.parse/5
(plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:212: Plug.Parsers.reduce/4
(api_pager) lib/api_pager/endpoint.ex:1: ApiPager.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
(api_pager) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: ApiPager.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
(api_pager) lib/api_pager/endpoint.ex:1: ApiPager.Endpoint.call/2
(plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
(cowboy) /home/erlan/Documents/Work/Erlang/Elixir/api_pager/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Controller.ex:

```
def upload_user_avatar(conn, %{"upload_file" => upload_file}) do
    IO.inspect(upload_file)
    json(conn, %{"message" => "Action will created, but file uploading still not working..."})
end
```

There is some screenshots:

Request Settings
[image: Request Settings]

Response from server
[image: Response from server]

really don't know 'cuz of what it happens... Have any ideas?

Comment: How are you sending this request?

Comment: Look at the screenshots, there is information

Comment: `Content-Length: 0` looks suspicious. Have you tried with another REST client?

Comment: Yeah, but it also `Content-Length: 0`. Maybe this is a magic and i need to create another project?

Comment: did you finally find a solution?

Comment: No, @OladipoOlasemo. It work fine on another created project